# Cannot read property 'authorization' of undefined

Tags: graphql, nestjs, nestjs-config, graphql-config

Please don't mark this question as 'duplicate'. I found similar questions elsewhere but couldn't find any proper solution.

When I use the `context` inside the `GraphQLModule` in Nestjs app configuration I never find the `req`. When I console this `req` it is undefined. Lot of time spent in this issue but in a vein.

**/src/app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ProductModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      debug: true,
      typePaths: ["./**/*.gql"],
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), "src/schemas/graphql.d.ts"),
      },
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      context: ({ req }) => { 
        console.log(req);  <======================== undefined !!!!
        return {req}
      },
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(MONGO_URI),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Comment: Maybe some hints in here: https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/48

Comment: Are you using express or fastify  as the underlying http engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem automatically solved after updating the Nest and Graphql packages.

I wondered!

It indicates that sometimes the packages can have any bug in itself.